# Why is Bhagvan Shiva known as Virupaksha?

Tags: shiva, symbolism, name

There is [Virupaksha temple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virupaksha_Temple) in Hampi - Karnataka, dedicated to Shiva. It is also part of the UNESCO World Heritage Sites. Similarly, there is a [Virupaksha temple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virupaksha) in Pattadakal, Karnataka.

Virupaksha is a name used for Bhagvan Shiva. What is the significance behind this name?

Answer (score 3):

Virupaksha refers to the formless awareness all around us.

> *Virupaksha* means eyes without the form; many people use this word as a
>   name. *Virupa* means no form, and *aksha* means eyes, it means eyes
>   without the form. When you go a little deeper, then you see that the
>   consciousness can see without the eyes, feel without the skin, taste
>   without the tongue, and hear without the ears; this is Yoga Samadhi.
>   Such things start happening in deep ‘samadhi’, just like in dreams?
>   You dream without any of the five senses; you smell, taste, you do
>   everything, right? So virupaksha is the consciousness that has eyes
>   but no form.

Reference used: http://qnawithsrisri.artoflivinguniverse.org/2014/01/qna-with-sri-sri_7.html

Comment: Virupaksha also means 'one with odd eye..'referring to 3 eyes of Lord Shiva...

Comment: @Tezz Yup, third eye is essentially Agna Chakra or awareness